# insert data from external webpage to salesforce

Tags: integration, webservices

How to insert record from External webpage to Salesforce. I need to achieve it with java web app? 
I am not able to find out exact solution.
Thankful for your help in advance.

Comment: You didn't get exact solution. Did you get some related solution?

Comment: I got the salesforce docs. but i am not able to find sample code or something like that. which will give me idea how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce provide Partner WSDL to communicate with SFDC from external webpages.

Here is the head start for the same.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_partner_examples.htm

this is the create example using java.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sample_create_call.htm

if you are going to use PHP for your web app you can use PHP SDK to create new records

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Create_Delete_Undelete_Sample_(Partner)

Comment: Thanks Himanshu I will look in it. Will be back If I found any issue,